# JDOM XML Scheme Validation

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I am having problem with schema validation and JDom (ver 1.1.3). I didn't know how to resolve the issue. I would be grateful if anybody can help me.

Here are the stack trace of the exception I get at runtime, the code fragment that tries to build the Document and generate this exception and the xml file and xsd file.

Thanks.

```
[exception]  WARNING: Error on line 11 of document file:C:/dsol2/experiment_3.0.xml: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'experimentalFrame'. org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 11 of document file:C:/dsol2/experiment_3.0.xml: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'experimentalFrame'.
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:530)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:905)
    at nl.tudelft.simulation.xml.dsol.ExperimentParser.parseExperimentalFrame(ExperimentParser.java:130)
    at nl.tudelft.simulation.xml.dsol.ExperimentParser.parseExperimentalFrame(ExperimentParser.java:96)
    at dsol2.ConsoleRunner.main(ConsoleRunner.java:64)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:C:/dsol2/experiment_3.0.xml; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 57; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'experimentalFrame'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:518)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:C:/dsol2/experiment_3.0.xml; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 57; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'experimentalFrame'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:518)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:905)
    at nl.tudelft.simulation.xml.dsol.ExperimentParser.parseExperimentalFrame(ExperimentParser.java:130)
    at nl.tudelft.simulation.xml.dsol.ExperimentParser.parseExperimentalFrame(ExperimentParser.java:96)
    at dsol2.ConsoleRunner.main(ConsoleRunner.java:64)

java.lang.NullPointerException  at dsol2.ConsoleRunner.main(ConsoleRunner.java:67)
```

The java file

```
private static SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder(
        "org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser", true);
static
{
    builder.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", true);
    builder.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema",true);
    String xsd = "/xsd/experiment.xsd";
    builder.setProperty("http://apache.org/xml/properties/schema/external-schemaLocation", "http://www.simulation.tudelft.nl" + xsd);
}
...

Element rootElement = builder.build(input).getRootElement();  //throws an error here
```

The XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dsol:experimentalFrame
    xmlns:dsol="http://www.simulation.tudelft.nl" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <experiment>
        <model>
            <model-class>dsol.Model</model-class>
            <class-path>
                <jar-file>dist/dsol.jar</jar-file>                
            </class-path           
        </model>        
        <simulator-class>nl.tudelft.simulation.dsol.simulators.DEVSSimulator</simulator-class>       
        <treatment>
            <startTime>2015-09-01T00:00:00</startTime>
            <timeUnit>MINUTE</timeUnit>
            <warmupPeriod unit="MINUTE">0</warmupPeriod>
            <runLength unit="MINUTE">10</runLength>
            <replication description="replication 0">
                <stream name="default" seed="1"/>
            </replication>
            <replication description="replication 1">
                <stream name="default" seed="2"/>
            </replication>
            <replication description="replication 2">
                <stream name="default" seed="3"/>
            </replication>
        </treatment>
    </experiment>
</dsol:experimentalFrame>
```

The XSD file

```
    <!-- ############################### ROOT DEFINITION OF EXPERIMENT ######################### -->

    <xsd:element name="experimentalFrame">
        <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" name="experiment" type="dsol:experiment"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="experiment" mixed="true">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="model" type="dsol:model"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="simulator-class" type="xsd:string"/>                                                         
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="treatment" type="dsol:treatment"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

   <!-- ######################################################################################### -->

    <xsd:complexType name="treatment" mixed="true">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="startTime" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            <xsd:element name="timeUnit" default="UNIT" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="dsol:timeUnit"/>      
            <xsd:element name="warmupPeriod" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" type="dsol:period"/>
            <xsd:element name="runLength" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" type="dsol:period"/>
            <xsd:element name="properties" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" type="dsol:properties"/>         
            <xsd:element name="replication" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" type="dsol:replication"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="properties">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="property" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" type="dsol:property"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="property">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
                <xsd:attribute name="key" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="value" type="xsd:string"/>
           </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:complexContent>
     </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="period">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:double">
                <xsd:attribute name="unit" type="dsol:timeUnit" use="required"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="model">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="model-class" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="class-path" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" type="dsol:classPath"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>  

    <xsd:complexType name="classPath">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="jar-file" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>


    <xsd:complexType name="replication">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="stream" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" type="dsol:stream"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="stream">
        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="seed" type="xsd:positiveInteger" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="timeUnit">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="MILLISECOND"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="SECOND"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="MINUTE"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="HOUR"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="DAY"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="WEEK"/>                             
            <xsd:enumeration value="YEAR"/>                             
            <xsd:enumeration value="UNIT"/>                 
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>   
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using 1.1.3 instead of 2.0.6?

Comment: Forgot angle bracket on line 11 of xml ? `</class-path` should be `</class-path>`